# baidu MAPS in salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a unique requirement where i need to post baidu map for china as google maps are blocked their. Do any one have any idea regarding this how iam able to integrate baidu maps with salesforce as of now iam using the lightning map component which is picking the google map as default map for location tracking.

Comment: You have to build a component yourself using BAIDU JS API. Most of Baidu's documentation is in Chinese.

Comment: Any idea how to use that